# Moving 2d objects on a 3d plane - AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d

I have a 2d plane rotated on its x axis, with 2d display objects I want to move around on the plane.  Its pretty similar to a chess board:

http://static.open.salon.com/files/chess011237853612.jpg

The board is a rotated rectangle, and the pieces are just 2d display objects.  Whats the easiest way to manipulate those objects so they appear to be moving on the board?

Answer (score 1):

Animate their Y position based on a Z property and adjust the scale based on the depth of the board. Or just add chess pieces as 3d objects and adjust their z to move forward and back.